# Laravel link to controller action via ajax

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to call a controller method via AJAX in Laravel

My HTML link is:

```
<a href="javascript://ajax"  onclick="Update('{{ $id }}');" title="Update">
```

And my javascript function:

```
function UpdateTimeTable(id)
{
    if(confirm('Please confirm if you want to publish Time Table for this exam.'))
    {
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ExamTimeTable/save',
            data: {id: id},
            success: function() {
                 alert('success');
            },
            error:function(){
                 alert('failure');
            }
        });     
    }
    return false;
}
```

My controller method:

```
function postSave( $id=0 )
{
    DB::table('exams')->where('id', $id)->update(array('status' => 3));
    DB::table('examstat')->where('exam_id', $id)->update(array('status' => 1));
    die;    
}
```

Also, my route is defined as such:

```
Route::controller('ExamTimeTable', 'ExamTimeTableController');
```

I am getting the alert of the `success` function but the database values are not being updated.

Comment: Can you add the code for your `routes.php` as well.

Comment: Route::controller('ExamTimeTable', 'ExamTimeTableController');

Comment: How are you passing the `$id` from your controller to the view where you're using it in `Update({{ $id }})`?
By the way, why is the name of the function different in your HTML (`Update`) and JS (`UpdateTimeTable`)?

Comment: Name is same. Just a typo here. I am not passing id to the view. I just need to update database in controller. If there is any other way without ajax i will use that

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you're passing the id as `data`, but you are assuming (per `postSave` declaration) that the id is part of the route. Since the parameter `$id` of `postSave` never receives any value, it will get the default (which you set to 0) and I'm guessing you don't have any database rows with the id = 0.

In other words, in you ajax code you have this like `data: {id: id},` and, since the method is POST, on the controller you will have access to `$_POST['id']` or, if you prefer the Laravel way `Input::get('id)`.

So, one option is to update the controller method to:

```
// Remove the parameter, as it isn't filled based on the route.
function postSave()
{
    // access the $id value as the data of the request
    $id = \Input::get('id', 0);

    DB::table('exams')->where('id', $id)->update(array('status' => 3));
    DB::table('examstat')->where('exam_id', $id)->update(array('status' => 1));
}
```

The other option is to make the parameter `id` as part of the route and, in this case, your method receives the `id` as a parameter. So, if you prefer this way, you will need to change the following:

Route:

```
Route::post(
    '/ExamTimeTable/{id}/save',
    ['as' => 'route-name', 'uses' => 'ExamTimeTableController@postSave']
);
```

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ExamTimeTable/' +  id + '/save',
    success: function() {
        alert('success');
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('failure');
    }
});
```

And you can leave the PHP code as it is, because Laravel will automatically fill the parameter `$id` of the `postSave` method.